# Setting up Ajax Push Engine (APE) to play nice with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, ajax

I'm trying to setup Ajax Push Engine (http://ape-project.org) on a CentOS server.  I've installed the APE Server and verified that it is running correctly.  I setup a subdomain on a separate IP, but I still can't get the javascript to connect.  I think I am setting up the virtual host incorrectly, but I'm not completely sure.

```
<VirtualHost *> 
        Servername domain.com 
        ServerAlias ape.domain.com 
        ServerAlias *.ape.domain.com 
        DocumentRoot "/home/domain/public_html/ape/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

The DocumentRoot is what is confusing me.  If ape.domain.com is supposed to point to the APE Server at port 443, what would the DocumentRoot be?  I have it set to the folder that stores the JS, but it just shows those files in the browser when I try to connect.  I tried changing httpd.conf's "Listen" to just the IP of the site and no the IP of the subdomain, but I still didn't see any difference, and this caused httpd to crash about every 30 seconds.  I'm hoping I am just making some obvious mistake that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

open your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file... I'm not sure where that is located on your computer... I'm using a Mac and for me its under `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

look at what `NameVirtualHost` is set as.

set `<VirtualHost>` to the same thing... this is what mine looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   Servername localape
   ServerAlias ape.localape
   ServerAlias *.ape.localape

   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/APE"
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that helps